Prove that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{bc+a}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{ca+b}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{ab+c}}\ge \frac{\sqrt{6}}{\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}}$

For all $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers which has a sum of 3. Prove that:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{bc+a}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{ca+b}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{ab+c}}\ge \frac{\sqrt{6}}{\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}}$$

The problem was originally here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h3358754p31202013
For the problem in the link, it's clearly that $k_{max}=\sqrt{6}$
But how can we prove the inequality in this case? I tried to divide both side by $\sqrt{\frac{6}{ab+bc+ca}}$. Then we have to prove:
$$\frac{\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}}{\sqrt{6(bc+a)}}+\frac{\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}}{\sqrt{6(ca+b)}}+\frac{\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}}{\sqrt{6(ab+c)}}\ge 1$$
Now, substitute: $\dfrac{\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}}{\sqrt{6(bc+a)}}=x, \dfrac{\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}}{\sqrt{6(ca+b)}}= y$ and $\dfrac{\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}}{\sqrt{6(ab+c)}}=z$. Now the inequality become:
$$x+y+z\ge 1$$

LEMMA: For all $x,y,z$ are real constants satisfy $16x^2y^2+16y^2z^2+16z^2x^2+297x^2y^2z^2 \ge 1$. Then we will always have: $x+y+z \ge 1$

Fortunately, this lemma works well on this problem. Then, applying this lemma, our duty is just to prove:
$$16x^2y^2+16y^2z^2+16z^2x^2+297x^2y^2z^2 \ge 1$$
with
$\dfrac{\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}}{\sqrt{6(bc+a)}}=x, \dfrac{\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}}{\sqrt{6(ca+b)}}= y,$ $\dfrac{\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}}{\sqrt{6(ab+c)}}=z$
The problem needed to be prove now don't have square root and become easier, but due to the complicated structure and $a+bc$, so currently I have no full proof for this tough problem.
Can someone please give me any idea to simplify each formula and even a full proof.?
Thank you very much!!

Alternative proof.
WLOG, assume that $a \ge b \ge c$. Then $1 \le a \le 3$.
Let $X := bc + a, Y := ca + b, Z := ab + c$. Then the inequality is written as
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{X}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{Y}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{Z}} \ge \frac{\sqrt{6}}{\sqrt{ab + bc + ca}}.$$
Squaring both sides, it suffices to prove that
$$\frac{1}{X} + \frac{1}{Y} + \frac{1}{Z}
+ \frac{2}{\sqrt{XY}} + \frac{2}{\sqrt{YZ}}
+ \frac{2}{\sqrt{ZX}} \ge \frac{6}{ab + bc + ca}.$$
We have
$$\frac{1}{Y} + \frac{1}{Z} \ge \frac{4}{Y + Z}, \quad \frac{2}{\sqrt{YZ}} \ge \frac{4}{Y+Z}.$$
It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{1}{X} + \frac{8}{Y + Z} \ge \frac{6}{ab + bc + ca},$$
or
$$\frac{1}{bc + a} + \frac{8}{ca + b + ab + c} \ge \frac{6}{ab + bc + ca},$$
or (using $b + c = 3 - a$)
$$\frac{1}{bc + a} + \frac{8}{(a+1)(3-a)}
\ge \frac{6}{a(3 - a) + bc},$$
or (clearing the denominators)
$$8(bc)^2 + [(a-1)(19-3a) + 4]bc + a(a-1)(a-3)^2 \ge 0$$
which is clearly true.
We are done.

Is there any deeper meaning to the fact that the two terms $\frac{2}{\sqrt{XY}}$ and $ \frac{2}{\sqrt{ZX}}$ can be omitted in the proof? At first glance it looked like you would be able to prove a sharper inequality, and yet $\sqrt{6}$ does seem to be optimal. Also how did you know that specifically those two terms would be irrelevant, did you just randomly remove terms until something worked or is there some method to it?

@user23571113 The important thing is that the best case for the inequality $\frac{LHS}{RHS} \ge 1$ is $b = c \to 0$ that is $\frac{LHS}{RHS} \to 1$ when $b=c\to 0$. Actually this is an update of my old proof. In my old proof, I did not omit any terms, but the proof is complicated. Then I worked for a simpler proof. I tried to discard some smaller terms (because $b, c \to 0$) and found that the inequality is still true.
